# How to calculate angles based on sides in triangles

Tags: java

I need to calculate the angles of an right triangle with the sides: `screenX = 1920`  and `screenY = 1080`.

How can i calculate the angles alpha and beta, assuming that gamma is 90° (right triangle).

I've tried it like this:
`double alpha = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(screenX/screenY)); 
double beta = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan((screenY/screenX)));`
resulting in: `alpha = 45.0 beta = 0.0`

instead of the correct values: `alpha = 60.65 beta = 29.35`.

Comment: You are declaring them as ints (or maybe longs), so the int division is resulting in `1` and `0` respectively. You can avoid this by using `Math.atan2` (or by explicitly coercing them to doubles, of course).

Comment: Even though it was obv all the time, I didnt think about this. Thank you